# Android - GCM is not present in google-services.json

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm planning to add the notification functionality to my android app, I added GCM through Google Developer Console and I got the API key and I used this key at the server side to send notifications to devices, however my GCM receiver is not working I don't know why, moreover, GCM is not present in my google-services.json.Apart from this, I also sent my device token to the server and it's sent successfully.
I cannot find a clue why I'm not receiving my notifications.
Here's my manifest code:

```
    <permission
    android:name="com.example.android.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission 
    android:name="com.example.android.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<!--Services-->
    <!--Service for retrieving device token and sending it to the server side-->
    <service
        android:name=".utils.RegistrationIntentService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <!--Service for checking updated device token-->
    <service
        android:name=".utils.GCMInstanceIDListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <!--Service to catch notifications sent from the server-->
    <service
        android:name=".utils.GcmMessageHandler"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <!--Receivers-->
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.example.android.utils" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: Why use GCM when Firebase messaging is the now suggested:: "Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) is the new version of GCM."  https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/

Comment: As GCM is deprecated by google, you have to use FCM integration in android, here is the [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client)